# logistic regression with non boolean variables

Tags: regression

I have trouble wrapping my head around the concept of logistic regression and its interpretation for non-Boolean variables.

An example from our course material goes as follows:

> Calculating a generalized linear model in R for the formula
>   `liked(boolean)~ highCalories(boolean)`, the coefficients look like this
>
> Coefficients:

```
             Estimate  Std. Error   z value    Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)  -0.47367    0.04369    -10.841    < 2e-16  
 Calorie s   -0.71497    0.17398     -4.109    3.97e-05
```

> > 
>
> With the intercept being -0.47, the chance of liked being 1 with
>   highCalories being 0 is logit(-0.47) -> 38.4%
>
> If highCalories is 1, the chance of liked being also 1  is
>   logit(-0.47367-0.71497) -> 23.4%

So in the case of the examined variable being Boolean it's clear to me. Let's look at an example with non-Boolean variables:

> Coefficients:

```
             Estimate  Std. Error   z value    Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept) -3.806e+00  2.801e-01   -13.589    <2e-16   
day         -1.934e-03  1.862e-04   -10.387    <2e-16
```

this is for `MailIsRefound(boolean)~dayofstudy(numeric)`

Because dayofstudy is not Boolean, the logit for the intercept doesn't seem that meaningful, but for day we get `logit(-3.806e+00 -1.934e-03)` -> 2.1%

How is this value to be interpreted?

Comment: Does the "day of study" mean "total number of days in the study," or "Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday...?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply means that for *each* unit change in the predictor `day` (presumably the unit is 'days') the log odds ratio of the response changes by a step of $-1.934\times 10^{-3}$, i.e. the odds ratio of the response changes by a factor of $\exp(-1.934\times 10^{-3})= - 0.99880619$.  So for each change in the predictor of a week, the log odds ratio of the response should change by a step of $7\times-1.934\times 10^{-3}=-0.01358$, i.e. the odds ratio of the response should change by a factor of $\exp(-0.01358)=-0.9865118$.  Of course it's worth checking that this presumed *linear* relationship between the predictor & the log odds ratio of the response seems reasonable; just as with ordinary least squares regression, mutatis mutandis.

Answer (score 0):

The exponential of the parameters in a logistic regression can be interpreted in terms of Odds Ratio (p/1-p)/(p'/1-p'). You can view this link:

http://www.unm.edu/~schrader/biostat/bio2/Spr06/lec11.pdf

As you can see, exp(b)=OR for a binary covariate, and exp(b)^Lambda=OR of augmenting the numerical covariate in Lambda units.